# How to fix ' [Win error 5] access is denied' error while installing surprise in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm installing surprise package in anaconda and I got this Access denied error. I'm using windows 10. please see the error

```
C:\Users\Hp>pip install surprise
Collecting surprise
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/de/e5cba8682201fcf9c3719a6fdda95693468ed061945493dea2dd37c5618b/surprise-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Collecting scikit-surprise (from surprise)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.12.0)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.2 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.16.4)

Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (0.13.2)

Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.2.1)

Installing collected packages: scikit-surprise, surprise
```

> `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\scikit_surprise-1.1.0.dist-info'
>   Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.`

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use pip for packages that are available through the anaconda distribution.  Use `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise` or `conda install scikit-surprise`.  I only use `pip` for packages not available with anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Environment is Pip version, Python and OS. You need to install it as a user

First upgrade your pip:

```
pip install --upgrade
```

Then use the user privilege:

```
pip install --user surprise
```

For Linux users you install as root privilege. Ubuntu users do not have a root privilege directly so you have to use sudo:

```
sudo apt install <packagename>
```